# understanding the proof of $\int_A p'(t)dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 p'(t)dt$

Tags: differential-geometry, geometric-group-theory

I need to understand the proof of a theorem from a book called "geometric group theory by Graham and Roller".
The *theorem* says:

> Let $p:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$  be $C^1$-path. Then there exists an open subset $A\subset[0,1]$ such that $\int_A p'(t)dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 p'(t)dt(=\frac{1}{2}p(1))$.

and the *proof* is:

> Every point $s=(t_1,...,t_n)\in \mathbb R^n$ lying on the (topological) sphere $\sum^n_{i=1} |t_i|=1$ defines a partition of $[0,1]$ into two subsets $[0,1]=A_+^s \cup A_-^s$, as $[0,1]$ is covered by $n$ intervals and by definition $t\in A_+^s $ if it is contained in such interval, say $[|t_1|+...+|t_i|,|t_1|+...t_{i+1}|]$ where $t_{i+1}\geq0$ and $t \in A_-^s$ if $t_{i+1}$ corresponding to $t$ is negative. Then we have a (continuous!) map of our sphere to $\mathbb R^n$ given by $s\mapsto \int_{A_+^s} p'(t)dt -\int_{A_-^s} p'(t)dt$ which is by Borsuk-Ulam theorem vanishes at some $s$ in the sphere. Then we take the smallest two sets $A_+^{s_0}$ and $A_-^{s_0}$ for $A$.

Comment: I don't understand the equality $\,\frac12\int\limits_0^1p'(t)dt=\frac12p(t)\;$...I'd say the integral must equal $\,\frac12(p(1)-p(0)\,$ ...

Comment: Can you clarify which bit is unclear to you, please? Is it the application of Borsuk-Ulam theorem, or the construction of $A^s_\pm$, or how the vanishing of a map at a point $s_0$ implies the theorem, or something else?

Comment: @DonAntonio,sorry! it is $p(1)$ i changed it

Comment: @Kirill. in fact the the construction of $A^s_\pm$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pick some $n$ numbers $t_i$, with $\sum_i |t_i|=1$, then you get an increasing sequence $q_i = \sum_{j=0}^{i}|t_i|$,
$$ 0 = q_0 \leq q_1 \leq q_2 \leq \cdots \leq q_n = 1. $$
So the $q_i$ partition the interval $[0,1]$ into $n$ intervals. Then you take the intervals $[q_{i-1}, q_i]$ and put them into either $A_-$ or $A_+$ depending on the sign of $t_i$.

The point of doing this is that the map
$$f:(t_1,\ldots,t_n)\mapsto \int_{A_+}p'(t)\,dt - \int_{A_-}p'(t)\,dt $$
is a continuous map from the ball $\{(t_i)\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, so you can apply the Borsuk-Ulam theorem to it, and use the fact that $f(-t_i) = -f(t_i)$. Once you do, all you have left is to note that $A_+ = [0,1] \setminus A_-$, because of how $A_\pm$ are defined.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: yes it does, but why $\sum_i |t_i|=1$ and not $\sum_i |t_i|^2=1$? and if we think about $\mathbb R^2$ what the partition will look like? sorry if the questions are very silly!

Comment: @Rahman Taking $\sum |t_i|^2=1$ would also work (then $q_i=\sum t_j^2$): there is a continuous bijective map between $\{(t_i)\mid\sum|t_i|=1\}$ and $\{(t_i)\mid\sum|t_i|^2=1\}$, so for applying Borsuk-Ulam theorem it just doesn't matter. I don't think there is a nice visualization, you just get $[0,|x|]$, $[|x|,1]$, with $|y|=1-|x|$, with assignments to $A_\pm$ depending on signs of $x$ and $y$.